# Convert epochmilli to DDMMYYYY - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, epoch

I have a dataframe with one of the column containing timestamps respresented in epochmilli (column type is long) and I need to convert them to a column with DDMMYY using withColumn
Something like:
1528102439 ---> 040618 
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `from_unixtime`. Please read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val df_DateConverted = df.withColumn("Date",from_unixtime(df.col("timestamp").divide(1000),"ddMMyy"))